# Yearly archives w/ custom field

Tags: low-yearly-archives

Does anybody know of a way to output a list of yearly archives using a custom date field? Low Yearly Archives is exactly the functionality I need, but referencing a custom date field, not the entry_date field.

Thanks!
- B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box, but if you change the SQL query that the plugin uses, it should work with a custom date field (not taking DST into account, tho):

Look up this in pi.low_yearly_archives.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        CONCAT(t.year,t.month) AS ym,
        COUNT(*) AS num_entries
    FROM
        exp_channel_titles t
    INNER JOIN
        exp_channels w
    ON
        t.channel_id = w.channel_id
        {$sql_cat_join}
    WHERE
        w.site_id = '{$sql_site_id}'
        {$sql_category}
        {$sql_expired}
        {$sql_future}
        {$sql_status}
        {$sql_channel}
        {$sql_author}
    GROUP BY
        ym
    ORDER BY
        ym ASC
";
```

And change that to:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        FROM_UNIXTIME(d.field_id_XX, '%Y%m') AS ym,
        COUNT(*) AS num_entries
    FROM
        exp_channel_titles t
    INNER JOIN
        exp_channels w
    ON
        t.channel_id = w.channel_id
    INNER JOIN
        exp_channel_data d
    ON
        t.entry_id = d.entry_id
        {$sql_cat_join}
    WHERE
        w.site_id = '{$sql_site_id}'
        {$sql_category}
        {$sql_expired}
        {$sql_future}
        {$sql_status}
        {$sql_channel}
        {$sql_author}
    GROUP BY
        ym
    ORDER BY
        ym ASC
";
```

Where `field_id_XX` should be changed to whatever the actual field ID is.

Comment: Low! Thank you for the detailed answer. This is fantastic. I actually use Low Yearly Archives already for other purposes that rely on the entry_date functionality. Any chance that a future version might have a parameter that selects a custom date field?

Comment: Sure, I'll consider it.

Comment: Low, I just found this thread whilst hunting for an answer to the same question -- how to create yearly archives based on a custom date field rather than the entry date. I looked in the pi.low_yearly_archives.php file but couldn't see the code block you refer to in your answer (I did a quick 'Find' search for "$sql" and got no result). Has the code changed since your answer? Anyway, consider this a ‘+1’ request for the ability to hook into custom fields. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, code's changed since then. This is the version of LYA the query refers to: https://github.com/low/low_yearly_archives/tree/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**: [EEvent helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/eevent-helper) will match a custom date field to your entry's publication and expiration date if you can live with that.

**EDIT1**: sorry, misread your question. Thought you needed a custom year range

Combining Low Archives with the [dt plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin) should give you what you need.